# How to de-link an element from a tree

Tags: java, tree

I want to implement a de-link an element from tree.

- assume that de-link in not valid for "root"
- for example:
  We have a tree and I want to de-link "C1" element from the tree.
- expected : the all "C1" children elements will be related to the parent of "C1" element

print tree before de-link "C1" element:

- Visited node with value: A1
- Visited node with value: B3
- Visited node with value: C2
- Visited node with value: D3
- Visited node with value: B2
- Visited node with value: B1
- Visited node with value: C1
- Visited node with value: D1
- Visited node with value: D2

print tree after de-link "C1" element:

- Visited node with value: A1
- Visited node with value: B3
- Visited node with value: C2
- Visited node with value: D3
- Visited node with value: B2
- Visited node with value: B1
- Visited node with value: D1
- Visited node with value: D2

attach tree structure and test example:

```
public class Tree<T> {
private T value;
private Tree<T> parent;
private Set<Tree<T>> children;

public Tree(T value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.children = new HashSet<>();
}

public Tree<T> getParent() {
    return parent;
}

public void setParent(Tree<T> parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}

public T getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(T value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public Set<Tree<T>> getChildren() {
    return children;
}

public Tree<T> addChild(T value) {
    Tree<T> newChild = new Tree<>(value);
    newChild.setParent(this);
    this.children.add(newChild);
    return newChild;
}
```

}

```
 private Tree<String> createTree() {
    Tree<String> root = new Tree("A1");

    Tree<String> b1Child = root.addChild("B1");
    Tree<String> b2Child = root.addChild("B2");
    Tree<String> b3Child = root.addChild("B3");

    Tree<String> c1Child = b1Child.addChild("C1");
    Tree<String> c2Child = b3Child.addChild("C2");

    Tree<String> d1Child = c1Child.addChild("D1");
    Tree<String> d2Child = c1Child.addChild("D2");
    Tree<String> d3Child = c2Child.addChild("D3");
    return root;
}

public static <T> void printDfs(Tree<T> root) {
    Stack<Tree<T>> stack = new Stack<>();
    Tree<T> current;
    stack.push(root);

    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        current = stack.pop();
        logger.debug("Visited node with value: {}", current.getValue());
        stack.addAll(current.getChildren());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's one special case you have to think about. What happens when you "de-link" root node?

Assuming you want to "de-link" a node, called "A" that has a parent:

1. traverse to "A"
2. get reference to "A"'s parent "P"
3. for each element "i" in A.children:

   1. set i.parent to P
   2. add i to P.children
4. then remove all elements form A.children

This will fail when A is the root, but here comes the question from the first line

Off topic, there is Java library for automatic generation of Getters, Setter etc. called Lombok. https://projectlombok.org/. In my opinion it makes code look better

Answer (score 0):

I solved it :

```
 public static <T> void removeElement(T value, Tree<T> root) {
    Stack<Tree<T>> stack = new Stack<>();
    stack.push(root);
    Tree<T> current;
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        current = stack.pop();
        logger.debug("Visited node with value: {}", current.getValue());

        if (current.getValue().equals(value)) {
            for (Tree<T> child: current.getChildren()) {
                child.setParent(current.getParent());
                stack.add(child);
                current.getParent().getChildren().remove(current);
                current.getParent().getChildren().add(child);
            }
            current.getChildren().clear();
        } else {
            stack.addAll(current.getChildren());
        }
    }
}
```